# How to load first menu item by default with a different Router Link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have React Router setup in my Reactjs Project. The header Component has 4 different menu items. After login, I am getting only header component rendered but not first menu item component below it.

I have created a Homepage component which loads Header component and below that I gave Routes for different menu item pages. In the Header component for every Item, I linked it to the corresponding Item Page.

```
//Home Page Code.
<Router>
    <Header />
    <Route path='/Jobs' component={Jobs} />
    <Route path='/Admin' component={Admin} />
    <Route path='/Requests' component={Requests} />
</Router>
```

Comment: What page you want to load by default? Jobs one?

Comment: after login what will  be your first page?

Comment: What is *Router* component, can you share how you are importing it?

Comment: What is in your  <Header /> component. Please post it as well.

Answer (score 3):

To use react router you have to wrap your routes in switch.

Switch will render the first item that matches the current route.
Because you have no switch, the routes are ignored.

To render a default site, change the path of the last route to / and it will match everything.

By setting it as last element, it will always be rendered, if no other route above matches the current route.

```
<Router>
    <Header />
    <Switch>
        <Route path='/Jobs' component={Jobs} />
        <Route path='/Admin' component={Admin} />
        <Route path='/' component={Requests} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

Hope this helps. Happy coding.

Comment: v5 mentions path="*" for fallback component
https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/no-match

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `<Switch></Switch>` container around your routes:

```
//Home Page Code.
<Router>
 <Header />
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
    <Route path='/Jobs' component={Jobs} />
    <Route path='/Admin' component={Admin} />
    <Route path='/Requests' component={Requests} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Edited: to add path for home (path='/')

Comment: This will not render a fallback if the route is different from the 3 provided.